# I recently installed the windows installer of ubuntu (12.04) (dual boot) and it is a little buggy

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, mouse

For instance I go to System Settings > Mouse Settings:
After Changing the mouse settings I go to close the settings and it doesn't close unless I right click on the icon and close it. I have no idea why.

It tends to happen only when changing the pointer speed (acceleration and sensitivity): after changing I press the close window button and it just sits there

Answer (score 0):

The windows installer (wubi) is reported to have some bugs. In fact the same for release 13.04 was removed due to existing bugs. Maybe its fixed in sometime...